# SSH through intermediate host using control socket

Tags: ssh

I want to SSH to a machine C from machine A through B. Usually I would do:

```
A$ ssh user@B
B$ ssh user@C
```

I have to type passwords both times (no public key allowed). I would like to set up a control socket so that after typing both passwords I can ssh to C using the socket, perhaps typing something like:

```
A$ ssh -S socket C
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use B as a jump host:

```
ssh -J user@B user@C
```

---

If your usernames or hostnames are long, you can add them to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host hostB
    HostName some-long-hostname-of-B-or-its-ip
    User username-on-B

Host hostC
    HostName same-here-for-C
    User username-on-C
```

Then you can ssh like this:

```
ssh -J hostB hostC
```

---

The jump can also be configured for `ssh hostC`:

```
Host hostC
    HostName same-here-for-C
    User username-on-C
    ProxyJump hostB
```

Comment: @Fernando, I feel like your edits could be posted in an answer of their own - it's your original research based on what I've posted. If you could post them as a new answer, I'll be happy to upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

To complement gronostaj's answer, here is how you create a socket with -J:

```
$ ssh -M -S socket -J user@B user@C -fN
```

Then to use the socket to log in to C:

```
$ ssh -S socket C
```

This way you are not required to type any passwords.